# ISO8601DateFormatter returning nil for converting from valid string to date

Tags: ios, swift

I have an ISO8601 String that I want to convert to a Date object, yet I keep getting a nil even though it's a valid string. Here's my code:

```
        let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        isoFormatter.formatOptions = [
            .withFractionalSeconds,
            .withInternetDateTime,
            .withFractionalSeconds,
            .withColonSeparatorInTime,
            .withDashSeparatorInDate
        ]
        let date = isoFormatter.date(from: self)
```

My string is `2020-04-10T21:13:40.880000`, same thing happens with `2020-04-10T21:13:40` (no miliseconds)

Comment: probably too many milliseconds

Comment: Same error happens with no miliseconds

Comment: You are specifying that the formatter should expect a time zone, but there is no time zone in your string.

Comment: First step debug tip: When a DateFormatter (from `String` to `Date`) isn't working as you want because of a format, just do the reverse: print the `Date` to `String` with the format. `print(isoFormatter.string(from: Date()))` in your case shows `2020-04-21T11:52:00.416Z`. You'll see the differences with your test string. (The `Z`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

`.withInternetDateTime` is a combination of `withFullDate`, `withFullTime`, `withDashSeparatorInDate`, `withColonSeparatorInTime` and  `withColonSeparatorInTimeZone`. The option requires a time zone in the string and works with `"2020-04-10T21:13:40.880000Z"`, note the trailing `Z`.

The options `withDashSeparatorInDate`, `withColonSeparatorInTime` are redundant in your code (besides the duplicate `withFractionalSeconds`).

---

To omit the time zone you have to replace  `withInternetDateTime` with `withFullDate` and `withTime`

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
  isoFormatter.formatOptions = [
      .withFractionalSeconds,
      .withFullDate,
      .withTime, // without time zone
      .withColonSeparatorInTime,
      .withDashSeparatorInDate
  ]
```